# ElasticSearch incorrect mapping into object

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

I use Nest client to make operation in Elasticsearch using C#. I want to get all hits from Elasticsearch and map to List, but when i use my code, all object propert are null:

```cs
//T is type of City
public async Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync<T>() where T : BaseReadModel
{
 var searchResponse = _client.Search<T>();

 var list = new List<T>();

 foreach (var item in searchResponse.Hits)
 {
   list.Add(item.Source);
 }
 return list;
}

...
public class City
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Country { get; set; }
   public string State { get; set; }
}
```

ElasticSearch structure:

```
"hits":{
   "total":{
      "value":3,
      "relation":"eq"
   },
   "max_score":1.0,
   "hits":[
      {
         "_index":"magmadb",
         "_type":"_doc",
         "_id":"9d90637f-932e-4473-9e01-266e17626d85",
         "_score":1.0,
         "_source":{
            "Country":"Polska",
            "State":"Śląsk",
            "Id":"9d90637f-932e-4473-9e01-266e17626d85",
            "Name":"Jaworzno"
         }
      },
      {
         "_index":"magmadb",
         "_type":"_doc",
         "_id":"3132acd5-4284-4c64-a251-0a0c290d722a",
         "_score":1.0,
         "_source":{
            "Country":"Polska",
            "State":"Śląsk",
            "Id":"3132acd5-4284-4c64-a251-0a0c290d722a",
            "Name":"Chrzanów"
         }
      }
   }
```

[image]

*P.S. before that, I used a high level client to save object with specify type to elasticsearch and then everything worked. When I am using the low level client to save json data, my code above stopped working. However, the data structure in Elasticsearch looks identical.*

Earlier way to save data when everything was working (item from ES was correct mapping):

```
elasticClient.Index(item, i => i
      .Index(indexName)
      .Id(item.Id.ToString())
      .Refresh(Elasticsearch.Net.Refresh.True));
  }
```

Now i use:

```
var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(message);
elasticClient.LowLevel.Index<StringResponse>("magmadb", item.Id.ToString(), message);
```

Comment: Are you sure `elasticClient.LowLevel.Index<StringResponse>(..)` is valid request? can you check what you see in `DebugInformation` for response from this call?

Comment: I found a sollution. When i use low level client for save items in ES, first letter in property name was automatic uppercase.